# not able to perform OnKeyListener correctly

Tags: android, validation, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard, onkeylistener

I want to apply few number validation after entering text into edit-text.I tried to do it using `TextWatcher`, but it works properly on high versions only , not in lower version.

Hence I want to use `OnKeyListener` events. But that is also not working.

```
start_time_edit.setOnKeyListener(onSoftKeyboardDonePress);

private View.OnKeyListener onSoftKeyboardDonePress=new View.OnKeyListener()
{
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {

        if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        {
            Toast.makeText(CreateTimesheet.this, "checking event", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        return false;
    }
};
```

It never goes inside the If statement as it both the values doesn't match.

What should I do?

Comment: You should use `event.getAction()` instead `event.getKeyCode()`

Comment: You can add imeOptions="actionNext" in your xml code for start_tim_edit! See if it's working?

Comment: do you want to detect **next** key ?

Comment: have you checked answer?

Comment: you should have to response here if someone help you.

Comment: @NiranjPatel Not next, done key. I got the solution which is working. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use [setOnEditorActionListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.OnEditorActionListener.html) instead of setOnKeyListener on EditText.

Here is sample code, please try it.

```
start_time_edit.setImeActionLabel("Next", KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER);
start_time_edit.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView arg0, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                if ((event != null && event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                    Toast.makeText(CreateTimesheet.this, "checking event", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: sorry for the delay